# Merge git repo branch (with different history) into master branch

Tags: git, merge

I started a node.js app and react app under two separate repositories. Now I'd like to combine them.

I've already merged the react app repo to the node.js repo.

So the "master" branch holds the node.js repo.

The "merge-branch" holds the react repo.

It may not have be the proper way to go about merging to repos, but I'm trying to now merge "merge-branch" branch into "master" branch, so they can truly be united. (Right now if I git pull, I only pull the one branch, thus they're not fully combined.

Any suggestions on the easiest way to get "merge-branch" into "master"?

I've tried:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge merge-branch
```

and I get the error:

> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Answer (score 1):

Add this option to merge: `--allow-unrelated-histories`